# Unit testing a scoped function used as a filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, scope, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I need to write a scoped function within my controller that acts as a filter.

```
  $scope.filterR = function(s) {

    return function(c) {
        for (var prop in c) {
          if (c[prop].toSomething() >= 0) {
            return c;
            break;
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

This is how I'm using it.

```
<div ng-repeat="c in cus | filter: filterR(s)">
        </div>
```

The trouble I'm facing is how to test this specific routine in karma-jasmine.

My current test looks like this,

```
describe('check x', function () {
    it('check abc', function () {
      var $scope = {};

      var controller = $controller('SController', {
        $scope: $scope
       });
       expect($scope.filterResults('some_data')).toEqual(
         some_data
       );
    });
```

The filter works fine but writing test for it giving me an issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always preferable to use real scopes for testing, unless it is known that it's not:

```
var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
```

filterResults is expected to return a function. So it is

```
var filterResultsFn = $scope.filterResults('some_data');
expect(filterResultsFn).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
expect(filterResultsFn(...)).toEqual(...);
```